# IOS Count up minutes from a specified number

Tags: swift3, xcode8

In my Football stopwatch I’m trying to get my counter to start from 45:00 when secondHalfClicked is touched but can’t figure it out, I've tried setting the minutes to 45:00 when I touch to start the timer again but the counter still starts from 00:00. Can anybody advise me?
Thanks in advance

```
@IBAction func firstHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if startStopWatch == true {
        timerStart()
        startStopWatch = false
        seconds = 0
        minutes = 0

    }
}

 @IBAction func endFirstHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if startStopWatch == false {
        timer.invalidate()
        startStopWatch = true
        seconds = 0
        minutes = 45
        stopwatchLabel.text = "45:00"
    }
}

@IBAction func secondHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if startStopWatch == true {
        timerStart()
        seconds = 0
        minutes = 45
        startStopWatch = false
        tempTimelineLbl.text = "2nd Half Underway"
    }
}

    @IBAction func endSecondHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if startStopWatch == false {
            timer.invalidate()
            startStopWatch = true
            seconds = 0
            minutes = 0
            stopwatchLabel.text = "90:00"
            tempTimelineLbl.text = "Full Time"
        }
    }

func timerStart() {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(StopWatchVC.updateStopwatch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateStopwatch() {

    let stopWatchString = stopwatch.elapsedTimeSinceStart()
    stopwatchLabel.text = stopWatchString
 }


class Stopwatch {

    var startTime:Date?

    func startTimer() {
        startTime = Date();
    }

    func elapsedTimeSinceStart() -> String {
        var elapsed = 0.0;
        if let elapsedTime = startTime {
            elapsed = elapsedTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
        }
        elapsed = -elapsed
        let minutes = Int(floor((elapsed / 60)));
        let seconds = Int(floor((elapsed.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))));
        let timeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        return timeString
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you setting `minutes` to 45 but I don't see where you use it.

Comment: I thought that was me using it, where would I implement minutes to start at 45? I guess this is the part I'm struggling with

Comment: By "use it" I meant where do you use it to count with or to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort it this way

My Class

```
func elapsedTimeSinceStart() -> String {
        var elapsed = 0.0;
        if let elapsedTime = startTime {
            if firstHalfTime {
                elapsed = elapsedTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
            } else {
               elapsed = elapsedTime.timeIntervalSinceNow - 45*60
            }
        }
        elapsed = -elapsed
        let minutes = Int(floor((elapsed / 60)));
        let seconds = Int(floor((elapsed.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))));
//        print(elapsed)
        let timeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
//        print(timeString)
        return timeString
```

Then my IBoutlets

```
@IBAction func firstHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if startStopWatch == true {
            timerStart()
            firstHalfTime = true

@IBAction func secondHalfClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if startStopWatch == true {
            timerStart()
            firstHalfTime = false
```

Created a global var

```
var firstHalfTime = true
```